# How do I calculate a for loop to display in a listbox where the first loop is user input but the remaining iterations are calculated?

Tags: c#, loops, listbox

I am trying to create a loop that will calculate inside a listbox but run the actual calculation after the first statement and compound the remaining...

Here is my code:

```
 // Count Loop   
 int numdays;
 numdays = 1;

 // Declare and Assign Variables
 double organism, daysmultiply, dailyincrease;
 organism = double.Parse(OrganismTextBox.Text);
 dailyincrease = double.Parse(DailyIncreaseTextBox.Text);
 daysmultiply = double.Parse(DaysMultiplyTextBox.Text);
 ResultsListBox.Items.Clear();

 // Need to have daily increase texbox formatted as a percentage - unsure how
 for (numdays = 0;  numdays <= daysmultiply; numdays++)
 {
     ResultsListBox.Items.Add(" Day " + numdays + " Popualtion is " + (organism * dailyincrease));
     numdays = numdays++;
 }
```

The result of the calculation is a loop that calculates .6 each time it iterates. I am trying to figure out how to compound the loop each time.
Can someone please help?

Comment: question is somewhat not clear !

Comment: Why do you increment the _numdays_ both in the for loop and inside the loop? This is going to be 0,2,4,6,,,,,

Comment: Steve - I am completely new to programming and am taking a beginning course in C#. I am trying to calculate a loop that will iterate as many times the value entered into (DaysMultiplyTextBox.Text) is. My result is the calculation (for ex: if user entred 2 in organismtextbox and .30 in DailyIncreaseTextBox) .6 which does not compound from the previous interation. I am trying to understand why it will not compound after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Your values don't "compound", because you do nothing in the loop that would cause that to happen, i.e. to change the values of the variables involved in calculating your values.

Your loop has other issues as well: you increment the loop index twice for each iteration; and you unnecessarily reassign the result of the post-increment operator back to the variable (the whole point of the operator is to do that assignment implicitly).

You probably want a loop that looks more like this:

```
for (numdays = 0;  numdays <= daysmultiply; numdays++)
{
     ResultsListBox.Items.Add(" Day " + numdays + " Population is " + organism);
     organism = organism * dailyincrease;
}
```

or possibly:

```
for (numdays = 0;  numdays <= daysmultiply; numdays++)
{
     ResultsListBox.Items.Add(" Day " + numdays + " Population is " + organism);
     organism += organism * dailyincrease;
}
```

The first example simply multiplies the `organism` value by the `dailyincrease` value. The second example does that multiplication and then adds the result to the current `organism` value. It's not clear from your question which is appropriate; it would depend on what the actual meaning of `dailyincrease` is. That is, if it's strictly the scale applied each day, then the first example is correct. If it's a representation of the percentage *change* (e.g. the `0.6` to which you refer means that the population increases 60% each day), then the second example is correct.

Comment: Peter, Thank you so much. The second example worked. So, initially I was performing a single calculation with a single with each iteration because the calculation itself was inside the Result.Item.Add (), correct? By creating a separate statement for the calculation, this changes the values of the variable with each loop. Furthermore, I never needed the numdays = numdays++; at the end of the loop because it is already accounted for in the initial loop expression? Is this logic correct?  Again, I thank you so much for this. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Lloyd: _"By creating a separate statement for the calculation, this changes the values of the variable with each loop"_ -- no, not really. It's the _assignment_ that changes the variable. In C# (and many other languages) there is syntax you could use to do the assignment in the `Add()` method parameter list expression. And that would work too. It's the lack of the assignment that was the problem, not where the code was. I just think the code is easier to understand if the two aspects are separated.

Comment: @Lloyd: _" I never needed the numdays = numdays++; at the end of the loop because it is already accounted for in the initial loop expression?"_ -- that's correct. The `for` loop includes as its third component the program statement to increment the counter, so there's no need to have that anywhere else.